# how to store the file arrays into class and calculate number of people having matching answers as the class's stored answers?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I was trying to calculate each row of the file having matching answers as the exam solution as well counting each row's number of right answers using the exam solution.
I tried to calculate the number of people having the right answers as the test answers stored in the class, once reading the file and storing the file arrays into the class - after placing the file arrays into class constructor to calculate the answers, but I can't, as I get the wrong answers where the class doesn't calculate. 
How do you solve this in Java, where I can calculate and store the file arrays into the class?

ExamFile3.txt:

```
    A A A A A A B A A A B C A A A A C B D A
    B D A A C A B A C D B C D A D C C B D A
    B D A A C A B A C D B C D A D C C B D A
```

Exam solution:
B D A A C A B A C D B C D A D C C B D A

this is the class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/*
 * http://www.java-examples.com/read-char-file-using-datainputstream
 */

public class Exam {
 private static boolean pass; //passed if student passes exam
 private static int allRightQuestions=0; //counts number of people having full     marks
 private static int lessThan5score=0; //counts number of people having < 5 scores
 private static int lessThan10Score=0; //counts number of people having < 10 scores
 private static int totalCorrect; //number of questions being answered correctly
 private static int totalIncorrect; //number of questions being answered wrongly
 private static int questionsMissed[][]; //array for storing the missed question numbers
 private static int passNo = 0; //number of people passing by having at least 15/20
 private static int failNo = 0; //number of people failing by having less than 15/20 
 private static int row = 0;//for counting rows of 20 answers
 private static int column = 0; //for counting letter exam answers
private static String showanswers = new String("B D A A C A B A C D B C D A D C C B D A");//the exam solution
String[] realanswers = new String[20];
private static String showresults[];


public Exam(String[] showresult, int rows)  
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    showresult = new String[rows];
    showresults = showresult;
    row = rows;

}   

public void sequentialsearch() //check the student having full marks
{

for ( row = 0; row<= showresults.length; row++) 
        if (showresults[row].equals(showanswers ))
        {
            pass = true;
            passNo +=1;
            allRightQuestions +=1;  
        }
        else
        {
        pass = false;

        }
    getallright();//counts number of people having full marks
    passNo();//count number of people passing
    }


public int getallright()
{
    return allRightQuestions;
}

public int passNo() //shows number of people who pass
{
    return passNo;
}

public void checkwronganswers(String[] showresult, int row)  //working out the number of wrong and right answers in test
{

    boolean found = false;
    int failure =0;
    for ( row = 0; row <= showresult.length; row++)
    for ( column = 0; column <= 20; column+=2)  
    {
        if (showanswers.charAt(column) == showresults[row].charAt(column))
        {
            found = true;
            totalCorrect +=1;
        }
        if (totalCorrect > 14 && totalCorrect <=20)
            {
            passNo += 1;    
            passNo();
            }
            else
            {
            failNo +=1; 
            fail();
            }
            if ( totalCorrect < 10)
            {       
           lessThan10Score +=1;
           lessthan10right();
           failure += lessThan10Score;   
                            }
            if ( totalCorrect < 5)
            {
                lessThan5score +=1;
                lessthan5right();
            failure += lessThan5score;
            }               
    }

            failNo = failure;
            fail();

        }

    public int fail()//number of people who failed
    {
        return failNo;
    }

    public int lessthan5right()//number of people having < 5 right answers
    {
        return lessThan5score;
    }

    public int lessthan10right()//number of people having < 5 right answers
    {
        return lessThan10Score;
    }

    public String show()
    {
        return showresults[0];
    }

    public boolean passed()
    {
        return pass;
    }

    public int totalIncorrect()
    {
        return totalIncorrect;
    }

    public int totalCorrect()
    {
        return totalCorrect;
    }

    public int questionsMissed()
    {
        return questionsMissed[0][0];
    }
}
```

this is the program:

```
    import java.io.*;
     import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ExamDemo {

private static Scanner kb;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int row = 0;
    String[] showresults = new String[30]; //student answers

    kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter text:" );
    String fileName = kb.nextLine();

    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner inputfile = new Scanner(file);


while( inputfile.hasNext() && row< showresults.length)  
{

showresults[row] = inputfile.nextLine();
System.out.println( "row" + row + ":" + showresults[row]);

row++;

}
System.out.println( row );
showresults = new String[row];
System.out.println( "accepted" );

Exam exam = new Exam(showresults, row); 
System.out.println( "reached"); 


System.out.println("students having all questions correct=" + exam.getallright());    
System.out.println("students having passed the questions = " + exam.passNo() );
System.out.println("students having failed the questions = " + exam.fail() );
System.out.println("students having less than
    5 the questions right= " + exam.lessthan5right() );
System.out.println("students having less than 10 
    the questions right= " + exam.lessthan10right() );
    exam.show();
inputfile.close();
}

}
```

Comment: please narrow down you question to a specific problem you are having.

Comment: The multiple choice answers you have are a serialized record, you need to convert into some data structure in your program which is amenable to your solution.  I would suggest vector/array for the grade storage, and a hash/map/dictionary of student tests, plus a key.  You should then be able to slice&dice as you need.